# Does function evaluation depend on place where it is defined?

Tags: debugging

I get an error message from `rtags` module while trying to call `rtags-taglist`.

While edebugging it I didn't find any problem with this function, although of course debugger printed the same error as during regular invocation.
As next step, I copied the whole `rtags-taglist` defun to `*scratch*` and evaluated it there (`C-x C-e`). Problem DISAPPEARS then.

So I decided to delete all the `*.elc` files from the `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/rtags/` directory, then restarted Emacs, then visited the `rtags-tagslist` definition, then re-evaluated it from its original location (`rtags.el`), but this DOES NOT solve the problem. Only copying the function definition elsewhere (`*scratch*`) helps.

How to explain it?

It's weird to me.

I'm running Emacs 24.5, with Spacemacs.

Comment: Show the definition of the function. Turn on `debug-on-error` and show the backtrace.

Answer (score 5):

The *rtags.el* file starts thus:

```
;;; rtags.el --- A front-end for rtags -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
```

So maybe the problem appears with lexical rather than the default dynamic binding.